# Unable to start mosquitto on raspberry pi buster

Tags: mosquitto

Was trying to install npm and got message "ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v11.4.0"
So unsinstalled nodejs and then mosquitto got stucked.
I can not start it .

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/mosquitto $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

pi@raspberrypi:~ $  sudo systemctl start mosquitto.service
Job for mosquitto.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status mosquitto.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

if I run

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status mosquitto.service
● mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2022-08-21 15:29:29 -03; 23s ago
     Docs: man:mosquitto.conf(5)
           man:mosquitto(8)
  Process: 820 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 821 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 822 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 823 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 824 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=killed, signal=ILL)
 Main PID: 824 (code=killed, signal=ILL)
```

if I go to the mosquitto folder

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/mosquitto $ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 19 14:20 ca_certificates
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 19 14:20 certs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 19 14:20 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  385 Aug 20 21:31 mosquitto.conf
```

And this is my mosquitto.conf file

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.gz

pid_file /run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

I have manually added ,listener and allow, to see if that would make any difference. But same result<

If I run, I get illegal instruction. Do not understand why...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
Illegal instruction
```

Also can not get version since I get illegal instruction....

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/mosquitto $ mosquitto -v
Illegal instruction
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/mosquitto $ mosquitto -h
Illegal instruction
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/mosquitto $ file 'which mosquitto'
which mosquitto: cannot open `which mosquitto' (No such file or directory)
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/mosquitto $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.75+ #1270 Tue Sep 24 18:38:54 BST 2019 armv6l  GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dpkg -s mosquitto
Package: mosquitto
Status: install ok half-configured
Priority: optional
Section: net
Installed-Size: 550
Maintainer: Roger A. Light <roger@atchoo.org>
Architecture: armhf
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 2.0.12-0mosquitto1~buster1
Config-Version: 1.6.10-0mosquitto1~buster1
Depends: adduser (>= 3.10), lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian3), libc6 (>= 2.28),   libcjson                 1 (>= 1.7.5), libmosquitto1 (>= 1.6), libssl1.1 (>=  1.1.1), libsystemd0, libwebs                 ockets18 (>= 4.2.1), libwrap0   (>= 7.6-4~)
Suggests: apparmor
Conffiles:
 /etc/init.d/mosquitto ee3001555cef9450c46fb2148c654cd1
 /etc/logrotate.d/mosquitto f74e922f3bf6b513f76d5e47fabfb322
 /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/README c1c6ae67f2def06c6a483be09b49d4de
 /etc/mosquitto/certs/README 4d8a70d4cefab07d4dabc5be1f786c1f
 /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/README b4ac621550824082a735732bfb42b51d
 /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf 6b48f97e52925e8cad9f32f991ef100d
Description: MQTT version 3.1/3.1.1/5.0 compatible message broker
This is a message broker that supports version 5.0 and 3.1.1 of the MQTT
protocol.
.
 MQTT provides a method of carrying out messaging using a publish/subscribe model. It is lightweight, both in terms of bandwidth usage  and ease of implementation.  


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /etc/apt
apt.conf.d   listchanges.conf  sources.list    trusted.gpg     trusted.gpg.d
auth.conf.d  preferences.d     sources.list.d  trusted.gpg~
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
raspi.list
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d $ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 284 Aug 19 10:55 raspi.list
```

Inside the file I have

```
#deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
deb http://mirror.ufam.edu.br/raspbian/raspbian/ buster main contrib non- free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
```

Any idea how to bring back to life mosquitto?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73437746/edit) the question to show the output of the following 2 commands `file \`which mosquitto\``  and `uname -a` (and please use code formatting for the output)

Comment: Please copy and paste what @hardlib asked; you need to use back quotes (\`) not regular quotes (') for `file \`which mosquitto\` `

Comment: Also include information about how you installed mosquitto originally. (Are you using the bundled version or have you added the mosquitto ppa?)

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:/etc/mosquitto $ file `which mosquitto`
/usr/sbin/mosquitto: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3,                    for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=a9b75833556dbb0444de422d597312e2eee75e91, stripped

Comment: Please edit the question when adding details. Run `dpkg -s mosquitto` and `ls /etc/apt/source.list.d`

Comment: I didn't ask for the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` I asked for the content of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory it should have a collection of `.list` files

Answer (score 0):

OK,

I have reproduced this, you installed from the mosquitto ppa which provides both mosquitto and a newer copy of libwebsocket.

The SIGILL is coming from the libwebsocket library that appears to have been built targeting ARMv7 not ARMv6 (which is what the Pi Zero [W]) is using.

I have raised this with the mosquitto maintainer, with any luck it will fixed soon and upgrading will fix the problem.

Comment: Where I can follow this ?

Answer (score 0):

Found similar problem here https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=334388
fixed with these commands

apt remove mosquitto libwebsockets18

apt install mosquitto libwebsockets18=4.2.1-0mosquitto1~buster1